# Produce multiple word reports from an rmd 'template'

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I'm really sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I couldn't find the answers I was looking for, but then it's possible I was looking for the wrong thing...

Say I have a dataset with data by the month or something, and I want to produce separate word document reports for each month of data.

I can easily make a word document for each month separately using markdown like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---
```{r}
test <- structure(list(Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
    2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("April", "August", 
    "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", 
    "November", "October", "September"), class = "factor"), Fruit = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Apple", 
    "Pear"), class = "factor"), Animal = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Elephant", 
    "Monkey"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Month", "Fruit", "Animal"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
test[test$Month == "January",]
```
````

But then I would need a separate rmd file for each month.

I found how to make this file from R:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("test.rmd",output_file = "test.docx", word_document()) # test.rmd is just the above code in a file
```

But is there a way to link it together and loop through the months to produce multiple reports all in one go?

I feel like the data should be put into a list in the R file, then looped through... but I don't know if that's right (is it bad to pass things from the global environment into the markdown file?  I feel like it doesn't do that for a reason... is there a better way?)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of parameterized rapports. It is possible to make different versions. This talks about building versions with different output for word and pdf I think, but maybe it could be modified to your needs?

[Link to rmarkdown.rstudio](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html)